# VS 12 shows new javascript runtime error in IE11P

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, internet-explorer-11, javascript

I just upgraded to IE11P to test out the updated dev tools.

Now when I start to debug a project through VS12 a new 0x800a138f JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference appears.

This happens when I type in my Ajax Combo Box that's bound to a data source with the text completion on.

This error has never popped up before the update to IE11, its never showed up in the browser consoles for IE10 and chrome.

when run without the debugger attached, it works like normal except it doesn't automatically all cap the text being entered under IE.

I am not really concerned over the error itself I would just like to suppress the annoying java runtime events.

Comment: If you do hear anything about the resolution of this issue, I'd appreciate your passing it along. I'm struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1924806.aspx?Unable%20to%20enter%20data%20into%20a%20combo%20box%20control). It looks like this is an issue with IE 11, something waiting for a solution from Microsoft.